# 3D rendering of 2D image and 3D segments

Tags: maps, 3d

I want to create a map with a height dimension; that is a rectangle image (actually a 2D map) plus 3D segments over it. I need to mark points with 3 coordinates and draw lines between them.

Is there something close to this?

```
|
|-------|
|\      |       <- 3D segments
| \      
   \                                <- Rotate the whole
----\---------
\    \        \
 \             \  <- 2D map
  \_____________\
```

Comment: Do you need a webapp? What do you want to do with these lines afterward? Show them somehow?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul webapp would be very nice but linux/windows app is fine too. I need just to draw lines and make a screenshot; from different viewpoints maybe.

Comment: Do you want to display a map too, or only the lines? Should the map be 3D too according to ground altitude?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I want to see map with lines; flat map would be ok if I can rotate it in 3D. I mean, adjust my viewpoint.

Comment: I made your question clearer and hopefully on-topic here. It is still in line with your original goal right?

Answer (score 0):

Check the API from [mapquest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/elevation/) and from Mapbox mapbox.com/blog/introducing-the-surface-api.

You can also download the elevation data from http://vterrain.org/Elevation/global.html or http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org and process it yourself.